# Matter for pre-certification use

Tags: matter

I'm developing a Smart Home product (Wi-Fi Only), in which all cloud-based communication is done, and LAN-eabled communication with our intended mobile application is done.

An upcoming feature is the interoperability with other systems, as Google Home, Apple Homekit, and Amazon Alexa.

The first approach is to support each of them natively, which will consume unnecessary time.

The second approach is to support Matter, which natively will support each of those systems.

Since Matter certification requires a Manufacturer membership ($7000/yr) and couple thousand bucks per device (and per model as I remember), beside testing fees, which is a barrier to support Matter at the moment.

Since there's a CA that signs the Manufacturer Certificate, which signs the product's one.

Given that there's an already open source project which one can run and test, to what extent this unofficial Matter support can run with other Matter systems?

So that if there's a good amount of products that allow dealing with anonymous/untrusted Matter nodes, I think we can just go now for.

Answer (score 1):

While the open source code for the protocol is available at
https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip
You may, for experimentation purposes, start with an available development solution such as https://community.element14.com/learn/learning-center/essentials/w/documents/28137/a-starter-guide-for-the-new-matter-smart-home-automation-protocol
https://www.nordicsemi.com/products/matter
After you get some experience with it, you can consider whether you need to join the alliance, paying the 7K fee or is there a route for you to piggyback on someone else's product for production (unlikely).